# Internet connection constantly dropping on home network

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I have Dell XPS with Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I am using my home network (and only this specific network), my internet connection keeps on dropping at random points in time. 
The network itself seems to be working as intended: other devices (as well as this same laptop when running Windows) work just fine.

However, I still have the feeling that the problem lies in how my home network was set up. It consists of a wireless modem and two access points. Whenever I am close to the modem, the internet connection seems to be more stable. When I move further away (and nearer to one of the access points), the connection starts dropping more and more often. Again: this only happens when running Ubuntu.

Comment: I would check the wireless encryption settings, make sure it's WPA2, not mixed mode (and WEP or WPA are outdated) and AES, avoid TKIP.

Comment: Seems to have helped. Thank you!